# Can anyone point me to information about ShapeRange().PlaceholderFormat.Position

Tags: powerpoint

I try to address a certain placeholder on a slide (but I have 3 body placeholders - so I try to identify them). While searching for other ways than using the positions I found the property PlaceholderFormat.Position which seems to have 0 for the Title and 1 for the Subtitle - but numbers from 10, 14, 15 for the others -- seems random to me. I can't find any information about that field.

I looked here:
[enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.placeholderformat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **.Position** property doesn't look especially helpful. It just shows the stacking or Z order of the placeholder, which you can ascertain by looking at the Selection Pane (**Home>Select>Selection Pane**). It also doesn't exist in PowerPoint 2010 and earlier, which could be an issue of your macro is to run on other computers.

The page you linked to shows the use of **.PlaceholderFormat.Type**. I would think that will be more useful to tell what kind of placeholder you are working on. Here is Microsoft's enumeration page for the .Type property: [PpPlaceholderType enumeration (PowerPoint)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.ppplaceholdertype)

Comment: The Problem arises when I use more than 1 placeholders of the type ppPlaceholderBody (ype 2) Body. Hence the simple check on PpPlaceholderType is not enough.

Comment: When you have 2 or more of the same type, you can distinguish those from each other by their ```.Top``` and/or ```.Left``` position on the slide, by the ```.Position``` property for their Z-order, or perhaps by their names.

Comment: Thank You again @John Korchoch - that's what I ended up doing.